# SQL Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "Arabic_100_CI_AI" and "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" in the equal to operation

Tags: sql-server

When i clicked right on my DB , this error appears
"SQL Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "Arabic_100_CI_AI" and "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" in the equal to operation. Could not use view or function 'dbo.sysdac_instances' because of binding error"

[image]
I don't know to change the collation

**UPDATE**
I tried this code to change default collation of DB But it gives an error
[image]

**Update2**
[image]
Please help me to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The issue with `sysdac_instances` is explained here http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/133981

Answer (score 4):

Your two tables are using different collation. You can tell your query to use a specific collation like this:

```
SELECT * FROM A JOIN B ON A.Text = B.Text COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

Or if you prefer to use the database default collation:

```
SELECT * FROM A JOIN B ON A.Text = B.Text COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
```

**Updated**

I think you need to set the database to single user mode

```
use master
ALTER DATABASE yourDB SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE    
ALTER DATABASE yourDB MODIFY NAME = [yourDBNew]
ALTER DATABASE yourDBNew SET MULTI_USER
```

Comment: O.K. but i which table should i execute this script ?

Comment: in your query,which table you trying to join ?

Comment: What do you mean with "SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE"

Comment: try this and say what happened

Comment: i think you have active connections to the database,first of all try this

Comment: I executed your code but problem still is not solved!

Comment: is it executed ?? what happened to this error,isn't it solved 
"the database could not be exclusively locked to perform the operation"

Comment: script executed successfully but original error still exists

Answer (score 1):

Try below syntax :

```
  SELECT * FROM Table1 PT
  JOIN Table2 TA ON PT.Value COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT = TA.Value COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
```

Comment: which table/ Stored procedure should i perform this script?

Comment: @MohamedNasr,Refer this URL for detail https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4395/understanding-the-collate-databasedefault-clause-in-sql-server/

Answer (score 0):

My issue was resolved this way, as two queries from different databases were joining.

[image]